# create counter for variable that is missed

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, counter

is there a way to create a counter for variables that are missed?
I am creating 3 counters - right, wrong and missed.
i set a time interval for 2 numbers.
if they match and i click the button, it is right.
if they dont match and i click the button, it is wrong
but if i dont click and the 2 number changes with the time interval. it is considered a missed.

but how do i increase the counter for missed?

my html as follows:

```
<td>Correct:</td>
<td id="correctScore"><span>0<span></td>
<td><span>Wrong<span></td>
<td id="wrongScore"><span>0<span></td>
<td><span>Missed<span></td>
<td id="missedScore"><span>0<span></td>
```

my script as follows:

```
var num1;
var num2;
var timerID;
var correctCount;
var WrongCount;
var missedCount;

correctCount = 0;
wrongCount = 0;
missedCount = 0;

timerID = setInterval(function() {
num1=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = num1;
}, 2 * 1000);

timerID = setInterval(function() {
num2=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = num2;
$('.numberStyle').css("font-size", "100px");
}, 2 * 1000);

$("input").click(function() { 

if (num1 == num2) {
correctCount++;
document.getElementById("correctScore").innerHTML = correctCount;

}   else if (num1 != num2) {
wrongCount ++;
document.getElementById("wrongScore").innerHTML = wrongCount;

}   else  {
missedCount ++;
document.getElementById("missedScore").innerHTML = missedCount;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks alot in advance. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason that explains why you use 2 timers for each number. You can generate two numbers in a timer like this:

```
timerID = setInterval(function() {
    num1=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
    num2=Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);

   document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = num1;
   document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = num2;
}, 2 * 1000);
```

For the missed counter, you can define a variable that checks if user answered or not and in the timer you can increase `missedCount` by looking that variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/rev86ta2/

Comment: Hey @İbrahim Duran, thanks for the helpful advice...in this situation. the button counter increases more than once when if i keep clicking. How can i make it only click once.

I tried 
    .on('click', function() and
    .off('click', function() 

but if i do that then then button only function once.. any idea to work around this?

Comment: You can prevent that by checking that answer variable in click function. See: https://jsfiddle.net/rev86ta2/1/

Comment: Hi @İbrahim Duran, thanks for your prompt reply. it works perfectly.

however, i dont quite understand this. please pardon me for rookie ignorance. does it mean that
    " if(!answered) { " is now part of the 2 seconds interval? or why does this liner help to enable only one click?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @İbrahim Duran, thanks alot for the explanation, i will practise more and get the hang of it. thanks.